# Automatically add Last-Modified header IIS?

Tags: iis, isapi, last-modified

Is there an ISAPI filter that can automatically add the Last-Modified header in IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS 6 onwards should already do this for you according to this MSDN article:

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/9c6405ef-b247-4c0c-b490-41a9b6682b1e.mspx?mfr=true